# getting "CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException "

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to retrieve the data of sqlite database . and put it on a string to display it further but I'm getting this error , Kindly help me in solving the error !

here is the logcat data showing error

```
    12-31 13:18:55.141: E/1.6(3833): 2222
12-31 13:18:55.191: E/1.2.2(3833): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 9 requested, with a size of 9
12-31 13:18:55.191: E/1.7(3833): 2222
```

and here is the piece of code which is showing the error!

```
public String getdata() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("1.1", "2222");
        String[] column = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_HOTNESS };
        Log.e("1.2", "2222");
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, column, null, null, null, null, null);
        Log.e("1.3", "2222");
        String result = "";
        Log.e("1.4", "2222");

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int iHotness = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_HOTNESS);
    Log.e("1.5", "2222");

    try{
        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext());
        {
            Log.e("1.6", "2222");

            result = result + c.getString(0) + " " + c.getString(1) + " " + c.getString(2) + "\n";
        }
    }catch(Exception e)
    {

        Log.e("1.2.2", e.toString());
    }

    Log.e("1.7", "2222");
    return result;
}
```

**Note :** after putting the below code in try catch it's moving to next activity but not showing any **result** data

```
        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext());
        {
            Log.e("1.6", "2222");

            result = result + c.getString(0) + " " + c.getString(1) + " " + c.getString(2) + "\n";
        }
```

next activity code  :

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    Log.e("1", "111111");
    HotOrNot info = new HotOrNot(this);
    Log.e("2", "111111");
    info.open();
    Log.e("3", "111111");
    String data = info.getdata();
    Log.e("4", "111111");
    info.close();
    Log.e("5", "111111");
    tv.setText(data);

    Log.e("6", "111111");
}
```

}

Comment: Means you are trying to use out of range value in cursor..Particularly at which line the error is showing??

Comment: your loop condition is wrong. you don't check the return value of moveToFirst

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a semicolon too much:

```
for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()); // look here :(
```

... so your `for` loop runs to the end of the cursor. Afterwards you try to get some data from the cursor, what fails, because you are already after the last entry.

Just use this one:

```
while(c != null && c.moveToNext())
{
    Log.e("1.6", "2222");

    result = result + c.getString(0) + " " 
                    + c.getString(1) + " " 
                    + c.getString(2) + "\n";
}
```

Most likely you can skip the `c != null`.

Comment: The `!= null` can be skipped. The query functions return a cursor or throw an exception. At least it won't become null inside the loop.

Comment: @laalto: in general you are right, though I think it's not a bad idea to check for null ;)